# upsert user based on federation id

Tags: soap-api

I'm trying to update a user using upsert based on federation id.

```
 <urn:upsert  xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
 <urn:externalIDFieldName>FederationIdentifier</urn:externalIDFieldName>
 <urn:sObjects  xsi:type="urn1:User">  
     <FederationIdentifier>1</FederationIdentifier>
     ....

 </urn:sObjects> 
 </urn:upsert>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> INVALID_FIELD: Field name provided, FederationIdentifier does not
>   match an External ID, Salesforce Id, or indexed field for User

Is it possible to use federation Id for this query? Is there any change I should make to this field in order to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation in soap api guide federation id value must be specified if the SAML User ID Type is Assertion contains Federation ID from the User record. Otherwise, this field can’t be edited. Make sure that SAML user Id type is Assertion contains Federation ID is checked or not under single sign on settings in setup. Attaching the screenshot for the same 
[image]

Comment: I check Assertion contains the Federation ID...., and I'm getting the same error.